# Windows service is being crashed after hosted two more windows services of same type

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am facing issue with windows service when 3 windows services are same type and hosted on same system.

Actually I have created a windows service in C# and hosted it on my local system. Actually this service process some document. It is working fine.

But problem comes when I created two more windows services to copy original windows service folder and also hosted on same system.

Structure of Window services

Service1

Service2

Service3

When I run any single window service then I didn't get any problem but if I run all windows services in once a time and they go to process the document, then some or all services crash.

I tried to debug it but unable to debug because of I don't know which windows service is going to process document, it happens randomly.

So, anyone can help me to figure out where is problem when we host multiple windows services of same type in same system.

Comment: What does the event log say, do you log any exceptions with a logger (NLog, log4net etc)? If not start adding those things.

Comment: try to write a log file..

Comment: it says>>> There was an error in the supply manager whilst loading host system items.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a Windows error. It is probably coming from your service. Your three services need to figure out what to do if it tries to process the document but cannot because of a sharing violation. (Also, why are you running three copies of the same service?)